# Nginx Amplify extended access logs and GoAccess virtual hosts

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, goaccess

I am running Nginx with installed Nginx Amplify. To get better metrics I've extend access log format to:

```
log_format  main_ext  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '"$host" sn="$server_name" '
                      'rt=$request_time '
                      'ua="$upstream_addr" us="$upstream_status" '
                      'ut="$upstream_response_time" ul="$upstream_response_length" '
                      'cs=$upstream_cache_status' ;
```

> Above format is from official Amplify documentation.

Everything works fine, extended metrics are included in Amplify web panel.

For better access log readibilty I also installed GoAccess package. When I start GoAccess with COMBINED log format it works. But I have configured few virtual hosts (that aren't show in GoAccess report page for now), so I should use VCOMBINED format, but it produces an error:

```
Token '+0100]' doesn't match specifier '%h'
```

To make it worked I've changed command to:

```
sudo goaccess /var/log/nginx/access.log \
        --log-format=VCOMBINED \
        --date-format=%d/%b/%Y --time-format=%T \
        -o /var/www/stats/report.html \
        --real-time-html
```

but same error appear. I have no idea how to create valid log pattern to work with amplify and GoAccess with virtual hosts support. I'm tried some tricks with awk but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

main_ext log format is something made up by Nginx Amplify, it is not VCOMBINED.

This should perhaps work for you

```
time-format %T %z
date-format %d/%b/%Y
```

log-format if you don't use a CDN or load balancers

```
log-format %h %^ %^ [%d:%t] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" "%^" "%^" sn="%v" rt=%T %^
```

log-format if you are behind a CDN or load balancers

```
log-format %^ %^ %^ [%d:%t] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" "%h" "%^" sn="%v" rt=%T %^
```